# PHP doesn't create session

Tags: php, session

After check, that's the problem actually:

```
Warning: Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current   setting of session.save_path is correct (/mnt/ramdisk) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Are you started the session with `session_start()` at the top of your file, before  any output?

Comment: I have it of course.

Comment: is it isset or isSet??

Comment: I check it with isSet()

Comment: Something that I don't know, please elaborate what is isSet() .?

Comment: The function: `isSet($_SESSION['logged'])`. You can use it in some conditional statement.

Comment: @MixedVeg PHP functions are case insensitive. The same as `isset();`

Comment: i know, but why to use it when you can use isset() ..?Reason?

Comment: ANd what if in `vms.php` you says a `var_dump($_SESSION); die();` right after the `session_start();`?

Comment: Hi, did you check by writing header first followed by setting the session variable??

Comment: @MixedVeg Why latch on to this? It's camel case. As lolka_bolka said, it's case insensitive.

Comment: @pavon147 Your issue is convoluted. You're asking about why a session variable isn't being set, but it's nested deep in some conditional ifs. So your problem could be either a problem in setting session variables, or in your logic. Separate these two out and do tests on each independently to narrow down to the cause. Then you can edit your question with a specific piece of code with a problem, rather than a blur of two possible issues.

Comment: @i-CONICA I've edited and got a new problem with it. So, there is no more space on the server?

Comment: There we go! :) No amount of fiddling with your original code would have fixed this issue. As it states, the device your system is running on is out of disc space. There are ways around it, like using a memcached server, but obviously the fix here is to clear up space. You can't install redis or memcached for session storage anyway as you've no disc space. :)

It's actually pretty urgent, so I'd clear up space asap.

Answer (score -1):

Add session_start() in the beginning of your code like this, and see if it helps.

```
session_start();
$file = fopen($path, "r");
        if($file) 
        {
            if(isSet($_POST['login']))
            {
                while(($line = fgets($file)) !== false) 
                {
                    $user_data=explode(";", $line);

                    if($_POST['login']==trim($user_data[0]))
                    {
                        if(md5($_POST['pass'])==trim($user_data[1]))
                        {
                            $_SESSION['logged']=htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
                            header('Location:vms.php');
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "
                        <script>
                            alert('Invalid login or password');
                        </script>
                    ";
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a `session_start();`

Comment: @pavon147 You do not show in your code snippet, nor mention in the description of the issue, that you have `session_start()` in the code, something that, if you did not have it, would have been the obvious issue. Personally I do not think that the downvote on this answer was justified.

Comment: @pavon147 I see, sorry for jumping to conclusions there (the point does apply to the downvoter then! :P ). :)